# How put number file limit primeng v9

Tags: angular, typescript, file-upload, primeng

I need to select only two file in primeng v9. According to [documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/v9-lts/#/fileupload)

I do this:

```
<p-fileUpload #form customUpload="true" maxFileSize="5000000" multiple="true" fileLimit="2"
>
</p-fileUpload>
```

the problem is that is not work because I can load more then two files. I want lad max two files. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

If fileLimit isn't working, I'd suggest trying latest version. Otherwise, the simplest thing I can think of:

```
<p-fileUpload #form customUpload="true" maxFileSize="5000000" multiple="true" fileLimit="2" (onSelect)="select($event)"
>
</p-fileUpload>

  select(event) {
    if (event.currentFiles.length > 2) {
      event.currentFiles.splice(-1,1)
    }
  }
```

A more elegant solution would be to disable the choose button on this event but the idea is the same.